# Can I make Windows use my USB drive as an extension of its disk space transparently?

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

In my college laboratories, any student can access a computer with their login info. If it is your first time, the computer will prepare a desktop for you and give you a partition of disk space.

I'm not sure how, but this computer barely has 1 MB of free disk space. I can't delete other users' files, since I don't have administrative privilegies.

It doesn't matter, because I just use my USB drive and work with it, so I don't really need more disk space here.

However, some programs I use need to generate temporary files in the file system. **They don't generate them in my USB drive**, so they only have 1 MB to make their files. This usually leads to errors for the programs. For certain reasons I'm not allowed to run these programs from my USB drive.

So, as an alternative, is it possible to make Windows 7 use my USB drive as an extension of its disk space? If my USB drive has 32 GB, then the programs will be able to generate up to 32 GB of temporary files, etc.

Comment: Are you a student or do you work for the college?  Either way, you would need to work with someone the proper domain credentials to make it happen. And it would have to be done on a per-computer basis.

Comment: @Usta: Student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to change the %temp% folder to point to the USB drive?

You just open a command prompt and :
`SET TEMP=**MyUsbDriveLetter**`